# JavaFX: Apply FadeTransition on Images

Tags: java, image, javafx

I am currently aware that FadeTransition works really well on nodes like the following:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);
FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), rect);
```

Is there a way I can do this on an Image instead of a node? I want to keep the **simplicity** of the 1 line of code and the **control** of choosing the duration. I am using Graphics Context to draw my images. Something like this would be perfect:

```
Image fadeMe = new Image("fadeMe.png");
FadeTransition ft = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), fadeMe);
```

But of course this doesn't work since FadeTransition requires a node. Is there a way to achieve this for an Image?

Comment: How are you displaying the image? Presumably you're putting it in an `ImageView`...

Comment: [ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) is a subclass of Class `Node`, so it's basically a node and your image should be added to an `ImageView` then apply the `FadeTransition`.

Comment: Oh im using `GraphicsContext` to display my image. Ill add that to my question.

Comment: In that case you can apply the fade transition to the canvas, though it will fade the entire canvas. A canvas essentially mimics a "direct drawing mode", which means the image is rendered (copied) onto the canvas. So if you want to animate the content of the canvas, e.g. fade only the image but nothing else, you would need to repaint the canvas, giving the image a different opacity, each time the frame is rendered. You almost certainly want to consider using a scene graph approach with nodes (including an `ImageView`) - instead of a canvas - if that's what you want to do.